# linux + atop + chart alternative from atop

Tags: linux, top

I use the atop in order to verify the performance top history
and know by the values the status for each time

my question is ,

what the alternative for atop that can view the values in chart?

or maybe some tool that can get the atop logs and convert these values to a chart

Answer (score 0):

I use munin (requires web server), you have lots of plugins to have charts of almost everything!! It's easy to create new plugins so if you need to control any non standard service you can do it easily
[Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

Comment: munin it's a little bit different solution. And with munin you can't get such detailed information as with atop.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [ttop](https://github.com/inv2004/ttop)!

Gave some more information here - https://serverfault.com/a/1151639/1071058

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573019)